# table is not rendering in backbone

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

I have a dynamic table created as following

```
app.View.FriendRequestTableView = Backbone.View.extend({
tagName: 'table',

className: 'table table-hover',

initialize : function(options) {
      this.options = options;
      this.render();
},
render: function() {
    $(this.el).empty();
    this.options.collection.each(function(user){
        var row = new app.View.FriendRequestRowView({model:user});
        $(this.el).append(row.el);
    });
    return $(this.el);
}
});
```

I checked and i saw the Row is properly constructed but the following line is not working

```
$(this.el).append(row.el);
```

I also have seen only table element is created but the table is empty.
Any ideas???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reference to "this" inside the iterator function for this.options.collections.each is probably a reference to window if I'm not mistaken. Creating an explicit reference to your view that the iterator function can use should solve your problem.

```
$(this.el).empty();
var _this = this;
this.options.collection.each(function(user){
    var row = new app.View.FriendRequestRowView({model:user});
    $(_this.el).append(row.el);
});
return $(this.el);
```